# xml Tableview nsxmlparsing

Tags: iphone, xml, tableview

[image]

see this tableview, i set 3labels in one row. the 3rd Label has more lines of text. it s not displaying i used the following code

// Configure the cell.
 UILabel *myLabel1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 20)];
 UILabel *myLabel2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 25, 300, 22)];
 UILabel *myLabel3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 50, 300, 40)];

Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

```
    myLabel1.text=aBook.title;
 myLabel2.text=aBook.pubDate;
 myLabel3.text=aBook.description;
```

//myLabel3.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap;

[cell.contentView addSubview:myLabel1];
   [cell.contentView addSubview:myLabel2];
   [cell.contentView addSubview:myLabel3];

//cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
       //Set up the cell

return cell;

i applied characterwrap,wordwrap,numberof lines, sizetofit, adjusttofontsizewidth, but not get back my result.
i need to display the 3 lines of text on 3rd Label i used with some alignment and also i need to remove HTML (&mdash) tags inside the Tableview because i am extract data from xml file (NSXMLParsing)
Help me out